# Sessions with DataMapper don't work due to an ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I have the following in session_store.rb. I'm running Ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.1.0.rc4

```
require 'dm-rails/session_store'
ActionDispatch::Session::DataMapperStore = Rails::DataMapper::SessionStore
Contendable::Application.config.session_store :data_mapper_store
```

I get the following output when making a request against the server:

```
[2011-10-19 22:07:14] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-10-19 22:07:14] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30) [i686-darwin10.7.4]
[2011-10-19 22:07:14] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=24805 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Oct 19 22:07:27 -0700 2011
  SQL (21.975ms)  SELECT "id", "session_id", "data", "updated_at" FROM "sessions" WHERE "session_id" = '7ecd5903df96a6d26cbbc69e6d397ce9' ORDER BY "id" LIMIT 1

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)):
```

Comment: Please post the rest of the error message and the method in your code that it corresponds to.

Comment: I may patch this, I think I know what it is. Rails 3.1 changed the arguments in the session store.  I'll get back to you and submit a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

https://github.com/datamapper/dm-rails/pull/28

You'll either have to use my fork from git (in your Gemfile) for now, or add a monkey patch to fix it.

Comment: Actually, now I'm getting this:

uninitialized constant Rails::DataMapper::SessionStore::ENV_SESSION_OPTIONS_KEY

Comment: Ugh. Let's see.  Will get back to you.

Comment: Can you try it now and get back to me, please? :) (It's the branch 'bugfix/rails-3.1-sessions', but I guess you found that)

Comment: Now I get:

gems/dm-rails-1.2.0/lib/dm-rails/session_store.rb:30: uninitialized constant Rails::Rack::Session (NameError)

Comment: Sorry (if you haven't guessed, I can't test it :P)... and now?  I think this should do it.  I'm trying to make sure it won't break in Rails 3.0 projects ;)

Comment: Now I get this:

dm-rails-1.2.0/lib/dm-rails/session_store.rb:30: uninitialized constant Rails::DataMapper::SessionStore::ENV_SESSION_OPTIONS_KEY (NameError)

Comment: Hmmm, I'm gonna have to set up a little Rails app, which I was hoping to avoid.  I may not get to this until tomorrow, sorry.  Feel free to take a look at the diff in my changes and try and debug it, however.  I'm definitely setting that constant o_O

Comment: I just made another change that may fix that. Looks like `||=` doesn't work with constants.  Not sure why.